# Mailing with win32com not rendering to_html() arguments

Tags: python, html, pandas, outlook

I can't make stylish arguments like `justify` or `col_space` works in emails' bodies.

Here is some sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from win32com import client

# software connection
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

# table
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'num_col': [250.0, 3.14159265359, 100000.639],
    'str_col': ['Some random text', 'Another text with different width', 'So what']
})

my_table = df.to_html(index=False, justify='center', col_space=500)
```

```
# function
def to_email(text, recipient, subject):
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(False)

# execution
to_email(my_table, 'guess@mail.com', 'Testing')
​
```

The window shows, but columns' width doesn't change and rows are left-justified, although the object `my_table` contains the specifications.

**UPDATE**: HTML output

```
print(my_table)
```

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th style="min-width: 500px;">num_col</th>
      <th style="min-width: 500px;">str_col</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>250.000000</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.141593</td>
      <td>Another text with different width</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>100000.639000</td>
      <td>So what</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following styles are not supported (min-width: 500px):

```
<th style="min-width: 500px;">num_col</th>
<th style="min-width: 500px;">str_col</th>
```

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of message bodies. You can find supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties described in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However, I don't see it directly helping me to solve the problem. Any tips on how I can setup the function to properly table rendering?

Comment: Well, I didn't find the full markup in your post. How could anybody suggest anything if the full HTML markup is not published?

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited the post now!